# Add Next and Previous Link on product page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, navigation, categories, product

I want to Add Next and Previous Link on product page in wordpress. Product Next and Previous link Work for same level Categories in wordpress.

Can Anyone Help me . How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

****Use this woocommerce hook ****

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'prev_next_product' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'prev_next_product' );
function prev_next_product(){
echo '<div class="prev_next_buttons">';
// 'product_cat' will make sure to return next/prev from current category
    $previous = next_post_link('%link', '&larr; PREVIOUS', TRUE, ' ', 'product_cat');
$next = previous_post_link('%link', 'NEXT &rarr;', TRUE, ' ', 'product_cat');

echo $previous;
echo $next;
echo '</div>';
```

}